# How does duplicate work?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

I asked a question a while back on askubuntu: [Removed several programs using "sudo apt-get purge wine\*"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/266867/ubuntu-12-04-lts-terminal-removed)

Which was recently marked as a duplicate of this question: [Deleted most of the packages using apt-get purge package\*; How can I get them back?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/527415/deleted-most-of-packages-using-apt-get-purge-package-how-i-get-them-back)

Now the other question has been marked as a duplicate of my question. How does that happen? Isn't there a check for such cyclic duplicates?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at the timeline, before yours was closed, somebody suggested a dupe in the other direction. I *think* normally if your was already closed as a duplicate, it wouldn't allow this. But when it was finally closed, the part of the site that collects the duplicate messages, *didn't* do a check. And silliness ensued.

I'll re-dupe against the one question to make things easlier to understand for future people.